# Save IO object to a file on Ruby

Tags: ruby, file, io, save, celerity

Im scraping a website using Celerity gem and I want to save an image but I dont know how to do it XD

With the next Celerity command I get an IO object

```
irb(main):260:0* image = @browser.image(:xpath, ".//*[@class='notdTop']/img").download
=> #<IO:0x277e07ae>
```

How can I save this object to a jpg file?? I tried this, but didnt work:

```
irb(main):261:0> image.flush
IOError: not opened for writing
```

but the IO object is not closed because I got this:

```
irb(main):264:0> image.closed?
=> false
```

Anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
image.save(filename)
```

http://rubydoc.info/gems/celerity/0.8.9/Celerity/Image#save-instance_method

Comment: Yep, download just returns an `IO` object, containing the whole website as HTML.